# How would I go about adding up values from different rows in tables with PHP?

Tags: php

Basically I want an "average price" for the items in my store (people re-sell them). Every time someone purchases a user's item, it will be added to the "Salles" (random name ftw) table. What I'm basically asking is let's say there's 2 rows in that table. The price in one of them is 100, and the other is 30. How do I make it add the two together to make 130? Would I use a while loop?

Comment: Post the structure of the table. You need to write a query that uses [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to compute the sum of prices (or [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) if you need the average price, etc), [grouping the records by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) some common property (product ID, probably).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from MySQL. You want to get the SUM of all the rows from a specific column.

SELECT    SUM(column)
FROM      myTable

Comment: but he didn't specify the data was coming from a database, he simply said 'table' (as in the general meaning)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very specific. I did mean a database.

Comment: @Alex this should work, if you prefer to do it in PHP, use the array returned by the database and do SUM($array)